# No Ingress firewall rule allowing SSH found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, kubernetes-ingress, firewall

No ingress firewall rule allowing SSH found.

If the project uses the default ingress firewall rule for SSH, connections to all VMs are allowed on TCP port 22. If the VPC network that the VM’s ## Heading ##network interface is in has a custom firewall rule, make sure that the custom firewall rule allows ingress traffic on the VM’s SSH TCP port (usually, this is TCP port 22).

[image: Connection Failed]

To investigate further, enable the VM's serial console. Then connect through the VM’s serial port, check the SSH server's listen port, and then compare the listen port number with the VM's firewall rules. The port numbers must match.

How to remove the network error, while initiating VM via SSH

Comment: Please provide the snapshot of the error you are getting while trying to ssh the VM. Verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic. If there is no firewall rule, create one following the below documentation provided and attach it to the infected VM.


You can follow these documentation to [Set-Firewall-Rules](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) & [Troubleshooting-SSH-Issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors).

Comment: Yes, I have checked the Firewalls rules and also attached the snapshot of the error displayed while accessing.

Answer (score 0):

**This error can occur for several reasons. The following are some of the most common causes of the errors :**

1. The VM is booting up and sshd is not running yet.
2. The firewall rule allowing SSH is missing or misconfigured.
3. sshd is running on a custom port.
4. Your custom SSH firewall rule doesn't allow traffic from Google
   services.
5. The SSH connection failed after you upgraded the VM's kernel.
6. The sshd daemon isn't running or isn't configured properly.
7. The VM isn't booting and you can't connect using SSH or the serial
   console.
8. The VM is booting in maintenance mode.

Please check for the above mentioned errors in serial port and refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#connection_failed) to resolve the issue.

**You can also try these steps :**

1. Stop the VM instance.
2. Click 'Edit' to edit the instance.
3. Under  ‘Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with value:

```
#! /bin/bash  
sudo ufw allow 22
```

4. Click 'Save'
5. Start the instance again, and SSH into it